# Which library has power function?

Tags: c, function

I am beginner c-programmer...I want to use power function in my program but ,I do not find any library that have power function?
Please introduce me a library have this function

Comment: what power function? as in mathematical exponentiation? `2^3 -> 8`?

Comment: by power function in math library you can do it..but please make a little search before asking questions like this

Comment: @amingholami thank you very much....

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <math.h>
double pow(double x, double y); // where x is the base, y is the exp
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <math.h>

double pow(double x, double y);
float powf(float x, float y);
long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```